# What would cause an OdbcDataReader to hang?

Tags: c#, odbc, datareader

In my C# code I have an ODBC datareader that's the results of a call to a stored procedure with a parameter.
When running the program by the customer, while retrieving the results from the datareader , using a while loop, at some point it will stop by the rdr.Read() command and just stand by for an undefined number of minutes and then continues.

```
while (rdr.Read()) {Somecode...}
```

What could cause this behaviour?

Comment: ODBC is an abstraction layer for a number of different data sources, without knowing exactly what type of data source you are connecting to, as well as the details regarding the procedure called, the type/amount of data being processed, it's impossible to say.

Comment: The `Read` method is probably accessing the database every time it's called, so what you describe might happen when the database is busy. Try reading the data into DataTable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> at some point it will stop by the
>   rdr.Read() command and just stand by
>   for an undefined number of minutes and
>   then continues.

Because it iwaiting for data. Basically look at the data source and figure out why it hangs.

The reader's contract is "either wait for data or throw an exception". Obviously your data suorce has a long timeout (or none) and data is not flowing in (as you expect).